# tk_optionMenu error "can't read "a": no such variable"

Tags: user-interface, tcl, tk-toolkit

I am trying to execute a simple code

```
global a
eval tk_optionMenu .qt.oc a  [list 1 2 4 8 16]
proc Run {} {
    puts "$a"
}
```

I have a button that associated to Run proc , when i press pres on Run button 
I receive the following error:

```
can't read "a": no such variable
can't read "a": no such variable
    while executing
"puts "$a""
    (procedure "Run" line 2)
    invoked from within
"Run"
    invoked from within
".top.run invoke"
    ("uplevel" body line 1)
    invoked from within
"uplevel #0 [list $w invoke]"
    (procedure "tk::ButtonUp" line 22)
    invoked from within
"tk::ButtonUp .top.run"
    (command bound to event)
```

any suggestions?

Comment: `$a` is not accessible from the `proc`. You could use `global` inside the `proc`, or use `variable` in the `proc` to create an alias.

Answer (score 1):

`global` must be used *inside* the scope where you are trying to access a global variable. For example:

```
proc Run {} {
    global a
    puts "$a"
}
```

Here's an excerpt from the [global man page](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/global.htm):

> This command has no effect unless executed in the context of a proc
>   body.

Comment: What's more, if you put a procedure definition inside another procedure definition, the inner definition has no special access to the variables in the outer definition at all. Tcl doesn't “do” lexical scoping.